# Why error "Unresolved attribute reference" showing only with disnake.User, but not with disnake.Member?

Tags: python, discord, autocomplete, hint

The weirdest thing is that ide autocomplete  work on both Member and User. But "Unresolved attribute reference" error showing only with User.
Why it's work this way and how to make Member to show this error too?

PyCharm 2022.1.1 (Community Edition)
Python 3.10
Disnake 2.5.1
[pycharm screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YI7Z.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the pycharm linter, I tried MyPy linter and it works as it should